# sveltekit 405 POST method not allowed on form actions

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using sveltekit to try and process a form using form actions but when pressing submit on the form, i get the following error:
`POST method not allowed. No actions exist for this page`

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong as i've followed the guidance in the docs https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions

I have my routes setup like so:[image]

In `page.server.ts`, i have the following code:

```
import type { Actions } from './$types';
 
export const addAction: Actions = {
  default: async ({request}) => {
    const fData = request.formData();
   console.log(44422, fData)
  }
};
```

In `page.svelte`, i have a simple form which is along the lines of what is mentioned in the docs:

```
<form class="flex flex-col space-y-6" method="POST">
</form>
```

Everything seems to be setup correctly just as displayed in the docs yet i keep getting a 405 error saying POST method not allowed. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addAction` is wrong, actions all have to be exported as `actions`.

Same applies to many other things, like `load`, the names have to match.